Equivalent in Julia CSV for Python Pandas' index_col parameter
I have a CSV file of the form (ignore the space on the first two rows, it's just for good alignment of the letters):
 , ,E,E,F,F
 , ,G,H,G,H
A,C,1,2,3,4
A,D,5,6,7,8
B,C,9,0,1,2
B,D,3,4,5,6

In Python, by creating a dataframe with pandas library as follows:
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1])

I was able then to get a value by mentionning the values of the header rows and index columns:
>>> df.loc[("A","D"), ("E","G")]
5

But in Julia, with the CSV and DataFrame packages, I can only "group" rows as header, but not columns. For now, I do:
df = CSV.read(path, DataFrame, header=[1,2], normalizenames=true) 

I could not find in the documentation of the function (https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/reading.html) any option enabling this feature
Is there a way, maybe using other functions or packages, to do in Julia what I can do in Python?

Julia DataFrames do not have row indices, so you'll have to filter for the rows you want, or use groupby to get the subdataframe for each indexed group.

It seems you might be looking for something like:
using CSV, DataFrames, NamedArrays

df = CSV.read(path, DataFrame; header=false)
M = NamedArray(parse.(Int,Array(df[3:end,3:end])),
  (
    map(String∘splat(*),eachrow(df[3:end,1:2])),
    map(String∘splat(*),eachcol(df[1:2,3:end]))
  )
)

which outputs:
4×4 Named Matrix{Int64}
A ╲ B │ EG  EH  FG  FH
──────┼───────────────
AC    │  1   2   3   4
AD    │  5   6   7   8
BC    │  9   0   1   2
BD    │  3   4   5   6

and to index:
julia> M["AD","EG"]
5

(instead of String∘, String.(map(...)) can be used.

Thank you, I get to the result you showed. Only, I cannot find how to access the elements. I tried, as proposed on the documentation of the package NamedArray, M["AC", "EG"], but it throws me the following error:
MethodError: no method matching indices(::OrderedCollections.OrderedDict{String3, Int64}, ::String)


You are right. The way it was written makes the indices of String3 type (which is more efficient, but not default string). To fix this, switch string for String in the construction. I'm fixing the answer.
